# Function in DataFixture class always return null but works in Controller

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

My function `findByDimensions()` works correctly in Controller but if I use it in the DataFixture class, it always returns null.

Code in controller:

```
$manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$smRepository = $manager->getRepository('Something\Repository');
$smRepository->findByDimensions(1, 2);
```

I got the correct object here. But if I use it in DataFixture class, I always get null:

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager) {
....
$smRepository = $manager->getRepository('Something\Repository');
$smRepository->findByDimensions(1, 2);
....
}
```

Where should be the mistake? The first manager is of the class EntityManager, the second is ObjectManager from DataFixture class.

Comment: Is the second code (DataFixture class) maybe executed in the Symfony test environment and using a different database?

Comment: That's not the issue, there is only one database.

Answer (score 3):

When you're loading fixtures your database is empty.

This is cause by purging on doctrine:fixtures:load 
You can check this out:

```
doctrine:fixtures:load --append
```

Comment: How do you work when an Entity has a relationship with another? Because you would need to put something on the Foreign Key. Do you need to create those other entities on the fly?